# WP7 Database and Casting error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i am a newbie for develop in c#
i am studing this example 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx
in this link you can see the my code where i think i have the problem:
http://pastebin.com/LYqzuqYb 
when i run app and click on button1 i have
i have a Invalid Cast Error, i use the cast only in

```
    Category = (DB.Elements)listPicker.SelectedItem
```

but i don't undestand where is the problem
best regads
Antonio

**More information**
i use this for insert element in listPicker

```
 public Inserimento()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Elenco> source = new List<Elenco>();
        source.Add(new Elenco() { Elemento = "Value1"});
        source.Add(new Elenco() { Elemento = "Value2" });
        source.Add(new Elenco() { Elemento = "Value3" });
        source.Add(new Elenco() { Elemento = "Value4" });
        this.listPicker.ItemsSource = source;
    }
```

Elemento is this class, i use this class for insert and store element in listPicker

```
namespace Example.ViewModel{
public class Elenco
{  public string Elemento
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}}
```

Comment: There's not enough code. Can you show the part when you bind data to listPicker? listPicker.SelectedItem clearly isn't of type DB.Elements, given your code it's probably of type Elementi. To be sure, put a breakpoint on the line then hover the mouse on listPicker.SelectedItem to see the type of the object. Or add this line just before: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(listPicker.SelectedItem.GetType());` then look the output window to see the type.

Comment: Well you're putting a list of `Elenco` in your listPicker, so you can't possibly hope to case it to a DB.Elements. Cast it to Elenco, then do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

When the `Inserimento` method is executed your `listPicker` contains a list of `Elenco` objects. Retrieving an item from that listPicker will retrieve **one** `Elenco` object. So this:

> `Category = (DB.Elements)listPicker.SelectedItem`

Should actually be this:

> `Category = (Elenco)listPicker.SelectedItem`